# JS async running multiple times, for each object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

*Edited to include pertinent information*

So I am running a JS bot for Telegram. And everything works great except every once in a while. A message will get sent to the TG group twice or 3 times. From the logging it seems it fires off the function for a single group twice/three in those instances. Why? I can't figure out. It should only be firing off once per object in the collection (using MongoDB)

Below is the code. Any help is much appreciated!

```js
\\index.js file
const Robot = require("bot");
const bot = new Telegraf(TGAPIKey);
const instance = new Robot(bot);

setInterval(async () => {
  try {
      instance.watchChanges();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return;
    }
 }, 7000);


\\bot.js file
const { transaction } = require("./crypt");

class Bot {
  constructor(bot) {
    this.bot = bot;
    this.transaction = new transaction();
    
    completeLoop(message) {
      console.log("successfull loop", message);
    }
    
    async watchChanges() {
      try{
        await Promise.all([
          
this.transaction.getTransaction(this.completeLoop.bind(this)),
        ]);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
 }
 
 module.exports = Bot;

\\crypt.js file
class transaction{
async getTransaction(callback) {
  let groups = await Group.find();
  
  groups.forEach(async (group) => {
    checkGroup(group).then(() => {
      console.log('Checked Group', group?.groupName);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('Failed to check group');
    });
  });
  callback('Looped Successfully');
 }
}

async function checkGroup(group) {
  //<--- Check Stuff--->
  if(checkStuff) {
    await sendMessage(msg)
    } else {
    return;
    }
}

async function sendMessage(msg) {
  await bot.telegram.sendMessage(msg).catch((error) => {
    console.log('error snd msg')
   }
```

Comment: a couple of things probably not related to your issue: no reason for `async (group)` since you never await inside the forEach - `callback('Looped Successfully');` will execute before any of the `checkGroup(group).then` will execute - because of asynchrony

Comment: perhaps if you `console.log(groups)` before the `.forEach` you'll see an issue

Comment: Will add that to see if I see anything, just wierd lol. Because it's random, will work fine for hours then boom double run, like if it grabbed the groups, from the group scheme twice or 3 times.

Comment: Also worth looking at the code that calls `getTransaction()` to see how it might be called more than once.

Comment: I wonder if it's to do with calling the callback before the `checkGroup` stuff runs

Comment: 1) `async getTransaction(callback) { ` is invalid syntax. 2) why do you have `async` and a `callback`? 3) `forEach` does not support `async` callbacks ...

Comment: @derpirscher - It would be valid syntax if this was part of a class definition.

Comment: Ok, so I updated the orginal post to include the other files that interact with this. It consists of 3 files, index.js, the main file, which calls the bot.js file every 7 seconds, then the bot.js file which calls the crypt.js file where it loops through the items in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of problems.  The main one that is probably confusing you is in this code:

```
async getTransaction(callback) {
    let groups = await Group.find();

    groups.forEach(async (group) => {
        checkGroup(group).then(() => {
            console.log('Checked Group', group?.groupName);
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('Failed to check group');
        });
    });
    callback('Looped Successfully');
}
```

You are calling `callback('Looped Successfully')` BEFORE any of the calls to `checkGroup()` have completed.  This is because `.forEach()` is a synchronous loop, but your asynchronous operations are all non-blocking.  So, the loop will run to completion, starting all your asynchronous operations.  Then, you call the `callback()` and then sometime later, the actual asynchrous operations will complete.

So, that will really confuse your logging.  You will log that you have a successful loop and then sometime later you will then log the results of each `checkGroup()` asynchronous operation.  So, your logging about when a loop starts and finishes will have no connection at all to when the actual operations in that loop log.  This will make things look really confused in the logging and could easily lead to the observation you're asking about.

In addition, mixing plain callbacks and promises really doesn't make any sense.  You should just return the promise and let the caller use that to manage completion and error returns.

Here's what I would suggest to align your logging with the actual asynchronous operations:

```
// index.js file
const Robot = require("bot");
const bot = new Telegraf(TGAPIKey);
const instance = new Robot(bot);

setInterval(async () => {
    try {
        instance.watchChanges();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
    }
}, 7000);


// bot.js file
const { transaction } = require("./crypt");

class Bot {
    constructor(bot) {
        this.bot = bot;
        this.transaction = new transaction();

        completeLoop(message) {
            console.log("successfull loop", message);
        }

        async watchChanges() {
            try {
                await this.transaction.getTransaction();
                this.completeLoop('Looped Successfully');
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
    }
}

module.exports = Bot;

// crypt.js file
class transaction {
    async getTransaction() {
        let groups = await Group.find();

        return Promise.all(groups.map(group => {
            return checkGroup(group).then(() => {
                console.log('Checked Group', group?.groupName);
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log('Failed to check group');
                // make sure error is communicated back to caller
                throw err;
            });
        }));
    }
}

async function checkGroup(group) {
    //<--- Check Stuff--->
    if (checkStuff) {
        await sendMessage(msg)
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

async function sendMessage(msg) {
    await bot.telegram.sendMessage(msg).catch((error) => {
            console.log('error snd msg');
        }
    }
}
```

**Summary of Changes:**

1. Changed getTransaction to return a promise, not accept a callback.
2. Change `groups.forEach()` to `Promise.all(groups.map(...))` to be able to track when all the asynchronous operations are done.
3. `return checkGroup(...).then(...).catch(...)` so that promise can be tracked.
4. throw error in `.catch()` so error is communicated back to caller, not just eaten
5. In the caller to getTransaction, use the returned promise, not a plain callback.

Note:  Your implementation still exposes you to overlapping calls to `instance.watchChanges()` (and thus more confused logging) if it ever takes more than 7 seconds for one call to `instance.watchChanges()` to complete.

Comment: Thanks for this! I will try out this solution and see if that resolves the double messages. For the watchChanges() piece, I also suspected that, I expect the number of groups to increase to a few thousand items. So it may take more than 7 seconds, essentially I need this to run in a continuous loop as it's constantly watching each group for changes.